# map.getCenter().lng() return object and string?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, object

I'm using Google Maps function map.getCenter().lng();

It returns the lng value but as soon as I try to do anything with the lng value i get errors eg:

```
var lang = sawdays.accordion.map.getCenter().lng();
var langTrim = lang.slice(0,5);
console.log( langTrim );
```

This just returns errors as lang is an object and not a string..

How do i get the value as a string from this method does anyone know?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `.toString();`

So:

```
var lang = sawdays.accordion.map.getCenter().lng().toString();
var langTrim = lang.slice(0,5);
console.log( langTrim );
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of `lng()` is a number (as per [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng)).

If you need it as a string you can do so by using this code:

```
var langTrim = ('' + lang).slice(0,5);
```

I doubt, however, that this is really appropriate. It seems you just want have a value with fixed amount of decimals. To do so, you could use [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) or [`toPrecision()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision)  like, e.g.:

```
var langTrim = lang.toFixed( 3 );
```

Comment: var langTrim = lang.toFixed( 3 ); worked, nice one thank you!

Comment: This fails on occasion.

Comment: @John It should work in every case you get a valid response by `lng()`. Any error messages?